# Swift Getting Numbers From A Model

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I press the buttons I want the text to go up 1,2,3,4,5 and Everything was fine until I tried to make a model and get the numbers from a model. Now when I press the buttons, nothing happens on the view side. It just stays in 0 and don't go up

Context View Code

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  ExatlonApp
//
//  Created by Alperen Sarışan on 26.05.2023.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var statistic = Statistic()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center){
            Color("BColor")
                .ignoresSafeArea()//Background rengi
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 100){
                Spacer()
                ImagesView()
                TextView(textAzul: String(statistic.marcadorAzul), textRojo: String(statistic.marcadorRojo))
                ScoreButtons()
                if statistic.marcadorRojo > statistic.marcadorAzul{
                    Text("El juego todavia sigue y el equipo Rojo esta ganando.")
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                else if statistic.marcadorRojo < statistic.marcadorAzul{
                    Text("El juego todavia sigue y el equipo Azul esta ganando.")
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                }
                else if statistic.marcadorRojo == 0 || statistic.marcadorAzul == 0 {
                    Text("El juego todavia no empezo, te avisaremos.")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                }
                else if statistic.marcadorRojo == statistic.marcadorAzul{
                    Text("El juego todavia sigue y esta empatada.")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScoreButtons: View{
    
    @State private var statistic = Statistic()
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack(spacing: 135){
            VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
                Button(action: {
                    statistic.marcadorAzul += 1
                    
                    if statistic.marcadorAzul <= 11{
                        statistic.marcadorAzul = 0
                    }
                },
                       label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                })
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonColor"))
                Button(action: {
                    statistic.marcadorAzul -= 1
                    
                    if statistic.marcadorAzul <= -1{
                        statistic.marcadorAzul = 0
                    }
                },
                       label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                })
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonColor"))
            }
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Button(action: {
                    statistic.marcadorRojo += 1
                    
                    if statistic.marcadorRojo >= 11{
                        statistic.marcadorRojo = 0
                    }
                },
                       label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                })
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonColor"))
                Button(action: {
                    statistic.marcadorRojo -= 1
                    
                    if statistic.marcadorRojo <= -1{
                        statistic.marcadorRojo = 0
                    }
                },
                       label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                })
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonColor"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

TextView

```
//
//  TextView.swift
//  ExatlonApp
//
//  Created by Alperen Sarışan on 26.05.2023.
//

import SwiftUI

struct TextView: View {
    
    var textAzul: String
    var textRojo: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 100){
            Text(textAzul)
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .padding()
                .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 3)
                    .padding(1)
                )
            //Azul
            Text(textRojo)
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .padding()
                .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 3)
                    .padding(1)
                )
            //Rojo
        }
    }
}

struct TextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextView(textAzul: "0", textRojo: "0")
    }
}
```

Model

```
//
//  Statistic.swift
//  ExatlonApp
//
//  Created by Alperen Sarışan on 26.05.2023.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Statistic{
    
    var marcadorRojo = 0
    var marcadorAzul = 0

}
```

Everything was working fine until I tried to make a model, Every time I press the plus button I want the text go up 1,2,3,4 but It's not working. How can I change the text to up to 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: You have two separate `Statistic` -- one for each `View`. Read about `Binding` and how to share state between parent/child views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the `@State private var statistic = Statistic()` in your `ContentView` and the one in your `ScoreButtons` do not share the same data source, so updating one does not update or reflect on the other one.
One solution is to create one data source they share through the concept of `binding`.

You can learn more here: [What is the @Binding property wrapper?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper)

So, Change `ScoreButtons` view to  accept a binding:

Convert `@State private var statistic = Statistic()`

to `@Binding var statistic: Statistic`

And where you call the `ScoreButtons` view, change `ScoreButtons()` to `ScoreButtons(statistic: $statistic)`

By using a binding, changes made to the `statistic` value inside the `ScoreButtons` view will also reflect outside of the view, and vice versa. It establishes a two-way connection between the view and the value, allowing the view to both read and modify the value.